# Visual Studio - How to change default C++ file name from "Source.cpp" to "main.cpp"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I go to add a new item in my Visual Studio C++ project

**'Add New Item' -> 'C++ File'**

The file name always defaults to `Source.cpp`.


I don't like that name, and I find myself changing it all the time to `main.cpp`.

Is there any way to change this?